Flattening a DataFrame in Spark after resolving nested field datatypes
Im having issues flattening a nested dataframe in spark which I have solved using a custom function but I am wondering if there is a better way to go about this.
The workflow is simple, the files arrive as zipped (gzip) json files in AWS S3 and Im using Glue/PySpark to process them. As they are already in a Glue catalog I use create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog() to create a dynamic frame which I turn into a dataframe, the schema of which is:
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- hour: string (nullable = true)
|-- year: string (nullable = true)
|-- month: string (nullable = true)
|-- day: string (nullable = true)
|-- events: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- open: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- eventId: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- amount: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- double: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- int: integer (nullable = true)

The events structs follow the same structure where each row has a unique id and some dimensions from the S3 partitioning. The nested events column can have multiplee named events, e.g 'open', which all follow the same structure: eventId, type and amount.
As amount has values of both types (e.g. 0 and 5.7), this causes some issues when using conventional ways to flatten and I typically end up with a flat dataframe but with the amount column split into 2 separate columns called 'int' and 'double'. I would need to cast these to a double before flattening to get the desired schema of:
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- hour: string (nullable = true)
|-- year: string (nullable = true)
|-- month: string (nullable = true)
|-- day: string (nullable = true)
|-- eventId: string (nullable = true)
|-- type: string (nullable = true)
|-- amount: double (nullable = true)

As this is in glue catalog with schema for event column:
"map<string,struct<eventId:string,type:string,amount:double>>" 
I tried using:
ResolveChoice.apply(dynamicframe, choice = "match_catalog",database=database,table_name=table) 

to resolve the amount before flattening however, this did not work. I also tried explicitly passing the schema as in
dynamicframe.resolveChoice(specs = [('events[].amount','cast:double')])

but this also did not work.
